# How to generate bootstrap div tag block dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have this div tags (bootstrap) in my asp.net page.

```
<div class="col-lg-4">
  <div class="panel panel-success">                       
     <div class="panel-body">
          <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server"  class="img-responsive" />                            
     </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
         <asp:Button runat="server" CssClass="btn-default" ID="txtEdit" Text="Edit" />
        </div> 
   </div>
</div>
```

They will be populated by data from SQL. What i need is to have the div tag `class="col-lg-4"` block dynamically generated whenever a new set of data is added in the database. How do i achieve this using javascript or asp.net.

Comment: Your question is too broad. Please show us how far you have done.

Answer (score 0):

As Win indicated, your question is rather broad. However, I will attempt to answer your question based on the information you have provided.

I'm assuming for the moment that the dynamic generation needs to occur when the page is loaded (whether initially or after a post back). The example I'm providing assumes that the work is purely done in ASP.Net, without any JavaScript involved.

Here's a snippet from an example .aspx page:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">

        <asp:Repeater ID="repeater" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                  <div class="panel panel-success">                       
                     <div class="panel-body">
                          <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server"  class="img-responsive" ImageUrl="<%#Eval("ImageUrl") %>" />                            
                     </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                         <asp:Button runat="server" CssClass="btn-default" ID="txtEdit" Text="Edit" />
                        </div> 
                   </div>
                </div>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>

    </form>
```

...and a snippet from the code-behind of the example page:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            repeater.DataSource = DataAccess.GetImages();
            repeater.DataBind();
        }
```

The "DataAccess" class in my example simply represents some approach for getting data from the database and binding that data to the Repeater control. For the purposes of my example, I've assumed that you've already figured out your Data Access approach. Notice on the .aspx example uses the "Eval" databinding method and that it assumes that "ImageUrl" is the name of either a database column or the property of each DTO (data transfer object), or whatever, returned as part of a collection  by the Data Access code. "Eval" provides one-way (read-only) data-binding to the ImageUrl property of the Image control you have.

I do see that you have an "edit" button in each block, but you haven't provided enough detail on how you'd use it in order for me to speak to how it could be implemented.

A JavaScript-oriented approach to a solution is, of course, also possible, but it's more involved. Using a server-side approach with the Repeater control, as shown in my example, could be exactly what you need :-) At the very least, it's a place to start.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks I needed a pointer Repeater `<asp:Repeater ID="repeater" runat="server">`. Which you have. Thank for the lead.